# How to create iOS app (ipa) via signing certificate and provisioning profile of client

Tags: ios, flutter, provisioning-profile, ipa, code-signing-certificate

i am making a flutter application for ios. I need to know, do i need client username and password to manage sigining in?. If i take the certificates and provisioning profile from client, can we make the ipa file?.

If you can provide me steps for achieving this goal. I am thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need only the p12 file(certificate along with the private key) and the provisioning profile from the client. Once you get these, install them by double-clicking and enter certificate password if any.

After the certificate and profile are installed, archive the app

```
xcodebuild clean archive -workspace <path_to_xcworkspace> -scheme <scheme> -sdk <sdk> -configuration <configuration>  -archivePath <path_to_xcarchive> -derivedDataPath <path_to_derived_data>
```

Then generate the ipa

```
xcodebuild -sdk <sdk> -configuration <configuration> -exportArchive -archivePath <path_to_xcarchive> -exportPath <path_to_ipa> -exportOptionsPlist <path_to_export_options_plist>
```

Sample exportOptionsPlist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.company.app</key>
        <string>Provisioning Profile</string>
    </dict>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```